# Trouble with some Functions

Tags: c

so I'm trying to call my OptionA function within a if statement in my getOption function but i get a error on line 59 saying "error expected identifier or '(' before '{'" so im just wondering how i can get my code to print out my line in the OptionA function. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function declaration
char getOption (void);
double OptionA;

int main(void)
{
  //local declaration
  getOption();

  return 0;
}//main

char getOption (void)
{
  //local declaration
  char option;

  //statements
  printf("\nMain Menu\n");
  printf("  A. Find the square root of a positive number.\n");
  printf("  B. Find the inverse of a positive number.\n");
  printf("  Q. Quit.\n\n");
  printf("Enter choice:");
  scanf(" %c", &option);
  if ( option == 'a' || option == 'A')
  {
     OptionA;
  }
  else if ( option == 'b' || option == 'B')
  {
    printf("\nnice");
  }
  else if ( option == 'q' || option == 'Q')
  {
    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\nError. Invalid Selection.\n");
    getOption();
  }
  return option;
}

double OptionA;
{
  printf("\nHey, it works.");
}
```

Comment: There is no `OptionA` function anywhere. Why do you think that it's a function?

Comment: If you're just learning C, do pay very close attention to formatting, especially *indentation*. This is extremely important for readability. C is a language that is indifferent to your mistakes, it will punish you severely, so keeping things orderly and organized is critical. Every single character matters. The mistake you have here would be made obvious if you indented the code properly, it'd simply look wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OptionA is not a function, it's a double.

```
double OptionA;
```

To declare a function in c, you should use ()
replace :

```
// PROTOTYPE
double OptionA;
// this is a double, you'd say :
double OptionA();
// this is a function which returns a double;
```

then in the getOption() function :

```
if ( option == 'a' || option == 'A')
{
    OptionA();
}
```

and in the function :

```
double OptionA()
{
    printf("\nHey, it works.");
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> *...call my OptionA function...*

`OptionA` is not a function the way you have declared it, called it, and defined it. The proper syntax for any function is:

```
return_value FunctionName (argument_data_type argument1, etc...)
```

If you do not want to pass any argument to your function, then you can have an empty pair of parentheses right after the function name, or you can have the keyword `void` inside the parentheses that come right after function name. **However**, the parentheses are required, else your function name will be confused for a variable by the compiler when declared (`double variable` is a variable of type double, and so is `double function`).

When the error is dissected:

> *error expected identifier or '(' before '{'*

It tells you that a parenthesis pair is required after the function name and the opening curly brace of the function body.

To fix this error, you should add a pair of parenthesis right after the function name at all points in your code where the function is called, declared, or defined. Change your function declaration at the top of your program from:

```
double OptionA;
```

To:

```
double OptionA(); // the pair of parenthesis is added here
```

Or:

```
double OptionA (void); // (void) is the same as () for this purpose.
```

Also change your function call to:

```
if ( option == 'a' || option == 'A')
{
    OptionA (); // pair of parenthesis added here too
}
```

And change your function header when you define it to:

```
double OptionA() // pair of parenthesis added he right before the function name
{
    printf("\nHey, it works.");
}
```

Comment: Actually, there's a big (BIG, ***BIG***) difference between `double OptionA();` and `double OptionA(void);` in C.  Both declare a function called `OptionA`, and both declare that the function returns a `double`.  However, the empty-brackets `()` version says nothing more; the function could have any (fixed) number of arguments of any type.  By contrast, the filled-brackets `(void)` version declares a prototype for the function and specifies that it takes no arguments at all.  After the declarations, the first allows `double x = OperatorA(1.23, "AAA");` and the second doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, but those parameters cannot be used inside the function definition, since they are not given a variable name or specific data type to call jnside a function. Hence, they are unused arguments. For the purpose of OP, both methods give the same end result (I tried and tested them both).

Comment: I disagree with your assessment.

Comment: The updated answer still says "(void) is the same as () for this purpose" and it is therefore still inaccurate.  They are *not* the same!  One is a prototype declaration, the other is just a function declaration.  One provides error checking that the other does not and cannot provide.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is it better __now__?

Comment: While you claim that empty parentheses and `(void)` are the same, your answer is wrong.